# Как показать данные в таблице после определенной даты?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Это ошибка которая у меня выскакивает.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.

Вот код

```
private void OnActive(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime TodayDate = DateTime.Now.Date; // init

            var query = from RentCarDB in this.dbContext.RentCarDBSet
                        where RentCarDB.StartDate.Date <= TodayDate
                        orderby RentCarDB.StartDate
                        select RentCarDB;
            this.rentCarDBViewSource.Source = query.ToList();
        }
```

Как показать данные которые после сегодняшней даты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно привести типы. Например:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(RentCarDB.StartDate.Date) <= TodayDate
```

Или воспользоваться функцией `TruncateTime`:

```
RentCarDB.StartDate.Date <= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(TodayDate)
```